# Fill all empty rows with a certain single value in mysql table?

Tags: mysql

I have a database, a table that is having empty rows '' nothing in them. 
I need to fill all those empty cells with certain singe value.
How can I do it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: havnt you heard of update  and insert into??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't batch edit all columns one column at each time

```
UPDATE table_name SET     COLUMN_name ='value' WHERE column_name=''
```

If you want to update all columns at once, write a php code for that and in a loop perform sql query!
Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You have several options, based on your definition of "empty rows".

if empty means null:

```
update tableName
set columnName = 'value'
where
    columnName is null;
```

if empty means not null, instead an empty string:

```
update tableName
set columnName = 'value'
where
    columnName = '';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1=value
WHERE length(column1)=0;
```

This should do you job.